# how to create a custom subclass of spring resttemplate

Tags: spring, resttemplate, spring-web

How do I create a subclass of spring rest template where interceptors are already set. The purpose of this is to avoid set interceptors everytime resttemplate is instantiated. I just want to use the instance of this custom class directly.

Comment: Can't you just extend `RestTemplate`?

Comment: Instead of instantiating, configure it in your context and retrieve it from there. That instead of creating a new instance each time you need one.